# Settings doesn't import in other file django

Tags: python, django

I have a file with pro project settings:
from .settings import *

```
DEBUG = True
ADMINS = (
    ('Abdullin Marsel', 'marsel.abdullin.00@mail.ru'),
)
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['caparolcenterspb.ru','localhost','127.0.0.1']
SECRET_KEY = "бла бла"
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'data',
        'USER': 'caparol_admin',
        'PASSWORD': '***',
    }
}
```

I have a file with the pro settings project in it I import the main settings, but they are not recognized, the first was the absence SECRET_KEY I added it from the main settings file and an error about no ads apps

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Which proves that the basic settings won't go wrong. I don't know what the problem is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To import settings, use `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: I need all the settings from the regular settings file to be included in the pro file. And this line that you wrote only allows you to access individual settings

Comment: you can access settings variable by using `settings.VARIABLE_NAME`. You can also do 
`from django.conf.settings import *`, this will import all variables and you can access them by their names `VARIABLE_NAME`

Comment: I need to import all settings from settings. I added image with my idea, sorry for russian

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2017/07/03/django-tip-20-working-with-multiple-settings-modules.html

check this.

Comment: dude that might be your connectivity issue. The link is valid search google for multiple settings modules in django.